# Получение информации о цвете пикселей определенной области окна программы. C#

Tags: c#, .net

Всех приветствую, прошу помощи, в каком направлении копать?
Суть задачи: написать бота, который будет сканировать определенную область экрана - полоску загрузки в окне сторонней программы и сравнивать с условным эталонным значением 100%-й загрузки. Сначала думал делать скриншот, обрезать нужную область и сравнивать с заранее подготовленным изображением, но возможно есть более подходящее решение?

Comment: А что загружается? Если файл - не проще ли мониторить на предмет появления новых файлов директорию, предназначенную для сохранения файлов?

Comment: Загружается трюм корабля рудой) пишу бота для eve online, поэтому могу получать только визуальную инфу

Comment: Без скриншотов никак.